# Вэб приложение андройд подлючение к серверу

Tags: android, веб-программирование, android-studio, веб-сервер, xampp

Хочу создать вэб приложение на Android studio, чтобы для получения данных оно соединялось с localhost. и оттуда получало данные из базы данных. Однако у меня возникли проблемы с эмулятором, поэтому использую устройство андройд подключенное через USB. Подскажите каким образом вообще можно подключится к серверу через устройство андройд на USB? localhost работает на xampp.

Comment: localhost у вас, видимо, в 2 разных местах - на андроиде и на компе. Если это так и вам нужно подключиться с андроида на комп то указывайте IP адрес компа, если андроид и комп находятся в одной сети.

Comment: у меня была такая проблема с эмулятором Genymotion, там даже указание своего ip в сети не позволяло подключиться.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите вместо localhost ip вашего компьютера, для получение ip адреса вы должный

1. Открыть терминал
2. Вести `ifconfig` если мак или linux а если Windows `ipconfig`